# zend framework muti-table query prototype

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

The tutorial of zend framework show that I can use Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet to return a model object using the dbAdapter ,select query and a model prototype. But in most case writing the website code I use multi-table query and the hydrator can not fix this problem but just a single table query. How should I deal with this kind of problem.
[hydrator doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html#zend-db-resultset-hydratingresultset)
And this problem can also happen when encounting the pagination which also only take one prototype.
[paginator doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the query, you might need a custom ResultSet that knows how to deal with the multi-row potential of a multi table query, and mapping that dataset appropriately.

Additionally, if you find yourself getting into very advanced object relationships with Zend\Db, that might be the time to start considering Doctrine2 (or a similar ORM).